# Im trying to pass an array of String, but i still cant get it right

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying display the array from class Taxi using class Place without "extends".

```
public class Testing {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      //creating obj of Taxi
      Taxi objTaxi = new Taxi();   

      //creating obj of Place
      Place objPlace = new Place();
      objPlace.displaySomething(objTaxi);
   }
}

class Taxi {

   String[] aaa = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};

   //public String getAAA() {

     // return aaa;
   //}
}

class Place {

   public void displaySomething(Taxi aaa) { //initialize obj of Taxi
```

i declared an array of String type to hold the data from the obj send to this method.
But it gave me error saying that "incompatible type" "required = String[]" "found Taxi".

```
      String[] array = aaa; //Cannot assign array in aaa to the array.

      //print all info in the array
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

         System.out.println(array[i]);
      }

      //System.out.println("string from Taxi : " + aaa.getAAA());
   }
}
```

Comment: Tips: Explain what you are trying to do in more detail, then ask a question.

Comment: What's wrong? Where's the question?

Comment: Dumping your code and saying it doesn't work isn't going to get much in the way of results.  Tell us what you are trying to do, what you expect to happen when you do it, what actually happens when you do it, mark your code to show us where the problem occurs, etc.

Comment: Hi, I strongly recommend you to take a java tutorial or read a little about java before posting this question since community will get mad :). Said that, take a look at [access modifier here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm). You need to define access modifier like "public" to your array and reference it. Or the more OO is declaring getters and setters to your array. Taxi is NOT an array Taxi is Taxi and contains an array aaa.

Answer (score 1):

your `aaa` which you pass to method `displaySomething` is instance of `Taxi`, so you can't assign it to array of Strings.

lets change your code little bit

```
class Taxi {
   String[] strings = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
   public String[] getStrings(){
   return strings
   }
}

class Place {

   public void displaySomething(Taxi taxi) {

      String[] array = taxi.getStrings();

      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

         System.out.println(array[i]);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: i kinda get what u trying to say..i think i know which part i got wrong. i should put array symbol ([]) when trying to return an array. like what u did "public String[] getStrings() {}"..

Comment: @user3657273 yes whenever you return array, you need to specify this,and yes [] means it is array

Answer (score 0):

You pass Place a Taxi object, and then assign the Taxi object to an String[] array. 
Maybe try to make a getArray method inside Taxi which includes the loop you put inside the Place class, and then inside Place call aaa.getArray, which in turn will print out the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = aaa;
```

aaa is a Taxi object so it makes no sense to set a String[] object to a Taxi object. What you want is:

```
String[] array = aaa.aaa;
```